# Expo push token not working on standalone app

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo

Expo notifications library is working when I run the app on the expo go app and it receives an ExpoPushToken but when i build the application with `eas build -p android` it doesn't work. I have put a console.log to check if the push token is loaded or not and apparently it's not working.
It is requesting all permissions and the FCM is configured in the FCM console and on the Expo credentials platform with the FCM server key. If it works on the phone on the Expo Go and not on the built app what could it be the problem?
Btw does expo servers send the messages to the devices, because on the documentation it does work, or do I need to change the push notifications to FCM directly and not Expo go servers?
This is getting me crazy pls help :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, there was an old build of my app, after deleting it the problem got solved. Thanks :)